# how to continue requesting when first response is not accepted in php?

Tags: php, laravel-5, guzzle6

I am a new for using Guzzle package i want to send data via  web api when response coming with status OK or NOT i do some action  otherwise status equal waiting i request again after 5second or status equal not yet sleep for 30 second.
this is my code

```
$client = new Client();
  $headers= [
            'Accept' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ];
        $body = [
            'phone2'=>'723457481',
            'amount'=>'200'
        ];
        $url = "http://192.168.31.51:8080/requesttrafic/";

       $response = $client->Request("POST", $url, [
            'handler'  => $stack,
            'headers'=>$headers,
            'form_params'=>$body
        ]);
        $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
       // this $contents can be  status 'ok','not' anything
```

So how can I send again according response status ?
Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect then, if your problem has been resolved then please mark the answer accepted to close this thread on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $response = $client->Request("POST", $url, [
        'handler'  => $stack,
        'headers'=>$headers,
        'form_params'=>$body
    ]);
    $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
if($contents!=='ok'){
    $response = $client->Request("POST", $url, [
        'handler'  => $stack,
        'headers'=>$headers,
        'form_params'=>$body
    ]);
    $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
if($contents!=='ok'){
    $response = $client->Request("POST", $url, [
        'handler'  => $stack,
        'headers'=>$headers,
        'form_params'=>$body
    ]);
    $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
}else{
  exit;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send it again if status is not 'ok' then:

```
if($contents!=='ok'){
    $response = $client->Request("POST", $url, [
        'handler'  => $stack,
        'headers'=>$headers,
        'form_params'=>$body
    ]);
    $contents = (string) $response->getBody();
}
```

if by status you meant http status then you can verify that like this:

```
$status = $response->getStatusCode();
if($status!==200){
 //your request again
}
```

or maybe i understood your question wrong. In that case please elaborate.

Comment: this answer is missing some argument  $contents is response data.

Comment: @jdamour, I have edited my answer, maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: this is logic i am using now multiple if statement with sleep() function

Comment: @jdamour, Perfect then, if your problem has been resolved then please mark the answer accepted to close this thread on stackoverflow.